Showing that this limit of an integral exists
I am struggling with the following exercise:
Let $f(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$, which is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.
Show that $\lim_{T \to \infty} \int_{0}^{T} f(x) \, dx$ exists (Hint: Use Chasles' theorem and integration by parts).
I unfortunately do not know how to correctly apply Chasles' theorem here. And when I perform the integration by parts, I only obtain
$\int_{0}^{T}\frac{\text{sin}(x)}{x}\ dx = \text{ln}(x)\cdot\text{sin}(x)\Big{|}_{0}^{T} - \int_{0}^{T}\text{ln}(x)\cdot \text{cos}(x)\ dx$
or
$\int_{0}^{T}\frac{\text{sin}(x)}{x}\ dx = \frac{-\text{cos}(x)}{x} \Big{|}_{0}^{T} - \int_{0}^{T}\frac{\text{cos}(x)}{x^2}\ dx$
which makes it difficult for me to proceed.
Could anybody maybe help me with that? Any help would be highly appreciated!

What is Chasles' theorem? In any case, your second integration by parts looks promising—what happens when $T\to\infty$?

We need to demonstrate that this improper integral converges.
First split the integral at 1 i.e. $\int_0^T \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \ dx = \int_0^1 \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \ dx + \int_1^T \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \ dx$.  the intrinsic $\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \ dx$ is amp right intrinsic Because $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$ as an result this condition is amp limited list. Now we focus on the second integral.
Apply integration by parts to $\int_1^T \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \ dx$ by letting $u = \frac{1}{x}$ and $dv = \sin(x) \ dx$.  extremely $du = -\frac{1}{x^2} \ dx$ and $v = -\cos(x)$. There fore
$$\int_1^T \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \ dx = \left[ -\frac{\cos(x)}{x} \right]_1^T - \int_1^T \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2} \ dx = -\frac{\cos(T)}{T} + \cos(1) - \int_1^T \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2} \ dx$$
As $T \to \infty$ $\frac{\cos(T)}{T} \to 0$ because $|\cos(T)| \le 1$. the condition $\cos(1)$ is amp true.  The remaining term is the integral $\int_1^T \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2} \ dx$.
We have $\left| \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2} \right| \leq \frac{1}{x^2}$. Because $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} \ dx$ converges extremely $\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2} \ dx$ converges extremely
So $\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_1^t \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \ dx$ exists and $\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_0^t \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \ dx$ too exists
